# Pressure change when volume and temperature both increase

Tags: gas-laws

By what factor does the pressure change if:

- the temperature rises from 0 to 100 degrees Celsius,
- and the volume is doubled?

$$
\pu{0 °C} = \pu{273.2 K}\\
\pu{100 °C} = \pu{373.2 K}
$$

Assuming $pV = nRT$:

Since pressure is proportional to temperature, neglecting the change in volume, the pressure would increase by a factor of $$\frac{373.2}{273.2} = 1.366\ .$$

Now since the volume is doubled as well, can I simply conclude that the pressure increases by a factor of $$\frac{1.366}{2} = 0.683\ ?$$

This is a task from a introduction to gases, I've mainly used the ideal gas law $pV = nRT$, but I wanna make sure my logic isn't flawed from the beginning.

Comment: This seems fine.

Comment: Cool! Appreciate the assistance